# How to implement on Backpress() in android without clearing previous page data?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. I have 2 activities namely `activity-A`,`activity-B`

activity-A has listview. activity-B has detail description of that list view. when pressing back arrow in activity-B , how to navigate to activity-A which out clearing list view in that activity-A

Also android phone has default `onBackpress()` and we will implement one back arrow in app bar.Both should navigate to activity-A which out clearing list view in that activity-A

Thanks in advance

Comment: where you get the data from ? in Activity A

Comment: @Iasya I guess you simply want to keep activity A on the stack, show B on top of it, then on back press to destroy activity B, so you will fall back to A, which should remember its state. If not, you would have to save activity A state onStop() and refresh it onResume(). I guess it's pretty basic Android behavior.

Comment: please show us you code

Comment: I think you are making new Adapter in your Activity for listView when resuming activity A

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Make your `onBackPressed()` like this in activity B

```
@Override
onBackPressed() {
    Finish ();
}
```

Note: do not finish() activity A while opening activity B.

Then, in your toolbar up button implementation, simple call `onBackPressed()`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

when you go back from activity B to A using back press it calls this method in activity B

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        super.onBackPressed();

    }
```

and call `onResume()` in your A

if your list Not saving it state make sure that you do not call refresh list in `onResume()`

it also depends that you call activity B from activity A without finishing Activity A